# Sorting multiple non-standard columns in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I have a list of files, with full path, that I need to sort in a bash shell.

The list will look like

```
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.10.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.1.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.2.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.12.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.1.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.3.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.18.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.20.cfg -- infomation grepped
/real/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.4.cfg -- infomation grepped
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.5.cfg -- infomation grepped
```

I need to have the list first sorted by the path, and then by the filename number.

I've tried:

```
 sort -t'.' -k 1,1 -k 2,5n fileame.txt
```

But it only ever sorts by the path. If I do:

```
sort -t'.' -k5n filename.txt
```

It works fine. How can I get the filenames in numeric order, after sorting by path?

Thanks

Comment: Do ALL your paths have the same number of components in them?

Comment: Yes. Every line follows the same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort up to `filename` first and then specify the `filename` number as a tie-breaker

```
sort -t'.' -k1,4 -k5n,5n filename.txt
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.1.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.3.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.12.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.20.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.1.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.2.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.18.cfg -- infomation grepped
/real/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.4.cfg -- infomation grepped
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.5.cfg -- infomation grepped
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.10.cfg -- infomation grepped
```

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
 Kaizen ~
 $ for ch in `sort testfile.txt | cut -c2-3 | uniq `
 > do
 > sed -n "/^\/$ch/p" testfile.txt | sort -t'.' -k5n ;
 > done ;
```

result :

```
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.1.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.3.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.12.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.20.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.1.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.2.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.18.cfg -- infomation grepped
/real/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.4.cfg -- infomation grepped
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.5.cfg -- infomation grepped
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.10.cfg -- infomation grepped
```

the approach is same as yours , i just added sed !!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a *sort key*, and then sort on that *sort key*, then remove the *sort key*:

Let's see...

```
$ while read line
do
    dirname=${line%/*}   #Directory names
    number=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\.\([0-9]*\)\.cfg.*/\1/')  # File number
    printf "%-60.60s %04d | %s\n" "$dirname" "$number" "$line"
done < filetext.txt | sort | sed "s/.* \| //"
```

This is reading in each line from `filetext.txt` and piping it into the `while read line` loop.

The `dirname` is using the `${parameter%word}` feature in BASH. This takes the value of `${parameter}` and removes the smallest amount from the right side that matches the pattern `word`. Thus, `${line%/*}` is taking `$line`, and is removing the last forward slash and all characters after that.

The `number` was a bit trickier. I noticed that you had something like `.44.cfg` at the end of the file name. That meant if I could find that particular pattern, I could find the file number. My `sed` command looks for a period, followed by zero or more numbers, followed by `.cfg`., and marks the numbers as a grouping. I then replace the entire line with the first grouping giving me the number.

Next, I print out the directory and the number using `printf`. I space fill the directory name to sixty characters (that could be increased if needed) and then a four digit number. This creates a sort key that looks like this:

```
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4                           0001
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4                           0003
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4                           0012
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4                           0020
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4                           0001
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4                           0002
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4                           0018
/real/path/software/version1.2.3.4                           0004
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4                          0005
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4                          0010
```

I append the line to this sort key, and then do my sort. After that, I remove the sort key from the line. The results:

```
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.1.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.3.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.12.cfg -- infomation grepped
/full/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.20.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.1.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.2.cfg -- infomation grepped
/long/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.18.cfg -- infomation grepped
/real/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.4.cfg -- infomation grepped
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.5.cfg -- infomation grepped
/total/path/software/version1.2.3.4/filename.10.cfg -- infomation grepped
```

Note I'm not depending upon a particular format for the file name as others have in their answers. What if you had a line like this?

```
/total/path/software/version1.2/filename.10.cfg -- infomation grepped
```

There aren't five decimal places in that line. Anything that is attempting to sort by breaking the fields via the periods will fail. The above will still work.

Comment: That's a lot of extra steps but I appreciate the answer. Luckily, the version number format never changes. Even if it means you have version 3.0.0.0

Comment: I knew that `sort -t'.' -k1,4 -k5n,5n filename.txt` would work, but since it was already suggested, I simply decide to take a different route. The sort key is a good technique when formatting might be more iffy. Even here, the period is a mere side effect.